# Screen resolutions are duplicated in the build version of the project Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a resolution change setting in my game, unity finds all permissions correctly in the editor. But in the build version, for some reason it duplicates each one. At the same time, no sorting of only unique values helps, because after debugging, I found that I was getting unique solutions, it seems this error applies only to the build version.

```
_resolutions = Screen.resolutions.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.width)
            .ThenBy(x => x.height).ThenBy(x => x.refreshRate).ToArray();
```

In editor

[image]

In build

[image]

Comment: is this on the same device? different `refreshRate` maybe? btw it already `sorts them by width and then by ascending resolution.`

Answer (score 1):

As user @derHugo noted, this is not a mistake, I just did not take into account the update frequency due to my inexperience.

[image]